# DataProvider parallel text input - multithreading issue

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, testng, testng-dataprovider

I want to realize parallel test run with DataProvider for testing an input field.

**Expected Result:**
Parallel tests for each text in DataProvider

1. Open page
2. Write "Text1" (or "Text2" or "Text3")
3. Press "Search" button

**Actual Result:**
One test with every strings in DataProvider as one

1. Open page
2. Write "Text1Text2Text3" (why so?)
3. Press "Search" button

How I can solve this problem where every string in DataProvider inputing into the field?
Here is my code bellow.

**TestNG.xml:**

```
<suite name="TestParallel" parallel="tests" thread-count="2" data-provider-thread-count="2" preserve-order="false" >
    <test name="ChromeTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.DataProviderTestParallel"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="FirefoxTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.DataProviderTestParallel"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="EdgeTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Edge" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.DataProviderTestParallel"/>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Test:**

```
@BeforeTest
@Parameters("browser")
public static void initSelenium(String browser) throws Exception {
    // Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
        // Create firefox instance
        FirefoxDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    // Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
    else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
        ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    // Check if parameter passed as 'Edge'
    else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Edge")){
        EdgeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
    }
    else{
        // If no browser passed throw exception
        throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@DataProvider(name = "forSearch", parallel = true)
    public Object[] forSearch() {
        return new Object[]{
                "Text1",
                "Text2",
                "Text3"
        };
    }

@Test(description = "Search text", dataProvider = "forSearch")
public void searchWithButton(String searchText) {
    SupportPageObject supportPage = new SupportPageObject();
    SearchResultPageObject searchResultPage = new SearchResultPageObject();
    supportPage.open();
    supportPage.isOpen();
    // Input text into field
    supportPage.writeQuestion(searchText);
    // Press "search" button
    supportPage.searchWithButton();
    searchResultPage.isOpen();
}
```

**UPD:** I've found that this issue reproducing when i have *data-provider-thread-count* is bigger than 1.
In that case it opens *thread-count* number of windows and then on the last one input *data-provider-thread-count* times text from DataProvider.
But still has no idea how to fix it and enter the DataProvider text into each opened window separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an Object[][].

```
@DataProvider(name = "forSearch", parallel = true)
    public Object[][] forSearch() {
        return new Object[][]{
                new Object[] { "Text1"},
                new Object[] { "Text2"},
                new Object[] { "Text3"}
        };
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Please, help me to make it clear:
In TestNG.xml my suite has to be parallel="tests" or parallel="instances" ?
My webdriver initialization has to be BeforeTest or BeforeMethod ?

Comment: parallel = "tests" and in BeforeTest

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. Nevetheless, "instances" and in BeforeMethod don't write all DataProvider objects into one input field, but Edge works only in one instance (i.e. "tests" in BeforeTest)